# Resources$NotFoundException fatal exception for custom view after proguard, on specific devices

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-resources, android-proguard

I'm getting the following stacktrace for crashes on few specific devices. Both the devices I faced the crash on are running OSv5.1

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #161: Error inflating class com.adroitandroid.stitchastory.ui.AppTextInputLayoutPlus
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
       at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:116)
       at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:88)
       at com.adroitandroid.stitchastory.HomeActivity$StartStoryFragment.onCreateView(HomeActivity.java:415)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2184)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1298)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentsToInvisible(FragmentManager.java:2323)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2136)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2092)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1998)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:709)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
       at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:116)
       at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:88)
       at com.adroitandroid.stitchastory.HomeActivity$StartStoryFragment.onCreateView(HomeActivity.java:415)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2184)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1298)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentsToInvisible(FragmentManager.java:2323)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2136)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2092)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1998)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:709)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0f007c
       at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1463)
       at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.isColorInt(AppCompatResources.java:161)
       at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.inflateColorStateList(AppCompatResources.java:108)
       at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(AppCompatResources.java:74)
       at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getColorStateList(TintTypedArray.java:136)
       at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.(TextInputLayout.java:244)
       at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.(TextInputLayout.java:183)
       at com.adroitandroid.stitchastory.ui.TextInputLayoutPlus.(TextInputLayoutPlus.java:19)
       at com.adroitandroid.stitchastory.ui.AppTextInputLayoutPlus.(AppTextInputLayoutPlus.java:16)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
       at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:116)
       at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:88)
       at com.adroitandroid.stitchastory.HomeActivity$StartStoryFragment.onCreateView(HomeActivity.java:415)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2184)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1298)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentsToInvisible(FragmentManager.java:2323)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2136)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2092)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1998)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:709)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

The resource mentioned is

```
    public static final int design_tint_password_toggle=0x7f0f007c;
```

in my R.java, basically not a resource I've defined myself. However, it is a custom layout that I'm trying to inflate here. For another such previous crash, I explicitly mentioned the text color in my view in xml to fix it. But this is different in that it is an android resource which it couldn't find. This isn't right on app launch either.

To add, this is a proguarded apk, I have the following in my proguard config file to retain the constants.

```
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
-keep class **.R$*
```

Also I've tried commenting out

```
shrinkResources true
```

for the particular build type, but it didn't fix this.

I'm using buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'

Support library version is 25.1.0 and [here is the layout file](https://gist.github.com/adroitandroid/adc1289e3ecd14c5bad9e6c12e5f684f) it's trying to inflate when it crashes. Line 161 is where the view related to the crash is declared. Pasting here for convenience.

```
<com.adroitandroid.stitchastory.ui.AppTextInputLayoutPlus
    android:id="@+id/contribution_til"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/done_ib"
    android:layout_alignStart="@id/cancel_ib"
    android:layout_below="@id/done_ib"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
    app:counterMaxLength="@integer/maxContributionLength"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:hintEnabled="false">

    <com.adroitandroid.stitchastory.ui.ContentEditTextPlus
        android:id="@+id/contribution_et"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/hint_add_story"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textCapSentences|textShortMessage|textMultiLine" />
</com.adroitandroid.stitchastory.ui.AppTextInputLayoutPlus>
```

Nothing fancy about the AppTextInputLayoutPlus, it just takes a custom typeface in the following manner.

```
abstract class TextInputLayoutPlus extends TextInputLayout {
    public TextInputLayoutPlus(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public TextInputLayoutPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public TextInputLayoutPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), getTextFont()));
    }

    protected abstract String getTextFont();
}
// in its own class file
public class AppTextInputLayoutPlus extends TextInputLayoutPlus {
    public AppTextInputLayoutPlus(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AppTextInputLayoutPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AppTextInputLayoutPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getTextFont() {
        return AppTextView.APP_TEXT_FONT;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know a way to fix this, and why this is coming up?

Comment: post your relevant code

Comment: You should probably mention which version of the design support library causes problem.

Comment: @BladeCoder good point, it's version 25.1.0

Comment: @AdeelJaved I've updated the question, please check

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with the above code but make sure your theme inherits from an AppCompat theme and that your are using the proper context to inflate the views (not the application context).

Comment: Also it seems you are using the data binding library, so you don't need custom views to set a custom font, you can do it using a BindingAdapter too, it makes the code cleaner.

Comment: @BladeCoder in the binding adapter pattern I know of, I pass the view and an argument to a static method. Won't that mean initializing with that argument for each instance of the custom view? I basically have two font typefaces in my app, one for app text, one for user-content text, and the custom view just initializes with the appropriate typeface. [Bit of a digression from the original question, but it'll be good to know :)]

Comment: To continue off-topic: yes, with the binding adapter you would need to repeat the binding for each (non-custom) view where you want to override the default font, so if you have many instances to change that would not be a "clean" solution. For custom fonts people usually rely on this or on a library called "Calligraphy" which allows you to define the custom font in a theme or in styles to avoid repeating it. If you do it yourself with a custom view it's also important that you use a font cache since loading a custom font is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess - the issue had nothing to do with the TextInputLayout, but more to do with the `ContentEditTextPlus`. Recently I identified an issue in the code of the `ContentEditTextPlus` and other such classes where I had overridden a setTextColor() mixing up a ColorRes int argument for a ColorInt or vice versa. That should explain the resource not found exception in `getColorStateList()`.